# Draw best fit line TeeChart (Delphi)

Tags: mysql, delphi, teechart, best-fit-curve

I'm wanting to take my Tchart (connected to a database query through a clientdataset) and draw a best fit line onto it. To do this (unless there is a built in method) I'm planning to work out the gradient of the first and the last data entries. How do I grab their coordinates to calculate the gradient for the line equation? This is what i want in psuedocode:

```
FirstXAxis := Datapoint[0].XAxis; 
LastXAxis := Datapoint[LastEntry].XAxis;
```

I know this isn't strictly a line of best fit but I couldn't think of anything else (I'm new to graphical delphi and databases). How do I find LastEntry?

Please help me out, Toby

Comment: Why not get the values from the clientdataset?  Plus, you cannot get the best fit line using only the first and last data values, you mus use them all.

Comment: How? And ok haha using the CDS would probably be easier.

Comment: There are examples with TeeChart (or available from their web site) showing how to chart directly from a dataset. Also, the datapoints are in an array, so you can use `DataPoint[High(DataPoint)]` to find the last entry.

Comment: when you say 'Datapoint' what is this? An attribute of the chart?

Comment: Can you define "best fit"? If you can't do that then nobody can implement anything, not even you! What you are currently proposing is not "best fit".

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the curve fitting function (*TCurveFittingFunction*). You'll find examples at *All Features\Welcome!\Functions\Extended\Curve fitting* in the new features demo available at the TeeChart program group created by the Pro binary installers. Examples on how to calculate line gradient are also included.